# counting rows before processing with a cursor tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count, rows, database-cursor

I have a SQL Server sp using a cursor thus:

```
DECLARE TestCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        tblHSOutcomes.strOutcomeName, 
        tblHSData.fkHSTest
    FROM
        tblHSData 
        INNER JOIN tblHSOutcomes ON tblHSData.fkOutcome = tblHSOutcomes.uidOutcome 
        INNER JOIN tblHSTests ON tblHSData.fkHSTest = tblHSTests.uidTest
    WHERE
        tblHSData.fkEpisode = @uidHSEpisodes

OPEN TestCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM TestCursor
    INTO @Result, @TestID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
...etc
```

It's working fine , however it would be nice to be able to check if the cursors query has any records before continuing to process through it.
if there a `@@` var that I can use to check this?

I know there is `@@RowCount` - but this has only the current number of rows processed - so isn't very helpful

Ideally I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
if @@cursorQueryHasRecords 
BEGIN
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
...etc
```

thanks

Comment: And why you can't use @@FETCH_STATUS itself?

Comment: And do you really need a cursor, they are often the worst choice. http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are able to declare your cursor as `STATIC` then you can use the built in function `@@Cursor_Rows`

[Cursor Options (Static/ReadOnly/Dynamic)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)

[@@Cursor_Rows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176044.aspx)

Comment: I believe you can also use @@CURSOR_ROWS with KEYSET cursors.

Comment: why must be either STATIC or KEYSET cursors for @@CURSOR_ROWS?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a example of how to use `@@Cursor_Rows`

```
DECLARE TestCursor CURSOR STATIC FOR
  SELECT <snip>

OPEN TestCursor

IF @@Cursor_Rows > 0 BEGIN

  FETCH NEXT FROM TestCursor INTO @compid, @logid, @category
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN   

  <snip>
END

CLOSE TestCursor
DEALLOCATE TestCursor
```

Please note that you need to declare the cursor `STATIC` (or `KEYSET`)

Answer (score 4):

```
if exists(
    SELECT
        tblHSOutcomes.strOutcomeName, 
        tblHSData.fkHSTest
    FROM
        tblHSData 
        INNER JOIN tblHSOutcomes ON tblHSData.fkOutcome = tblHSOutcomes.uidOutcome 
        INNER JOIN tblHSTests ON tblHSData.fkHSTest = tblHSTests.uidTest
    WHERE
        tblHSData.fkEpisode = @uidHSEpisodes
)
...
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. how to i wrap that in the cursor bit.. dont want to run that query twice..
Presumably i cant do 
decalre testcursor cursor for
if exists(select ....